# How remove/debug Stylus Asus pen which sends events every time laptop starts since is disabled

Tags: x11, xinput, libinput, i2c

Week ago stylus have been added somehow between devices (I do not have own stylus for few months) and spam me with events every time laptop starts:

```
$ sudo libinput debug-events | grep event5
-event5   DEVICE_ADDED            ELAN9009:00 04F3:2E36             seat0 default group5  cap:t  size 300x184mm ntouches 10 calib
-event5   TOUCH_DOWN              +69.894s  0 (0) 85.20/92.85 (255.67/170.92mm)
 event5   TOUCH_FRAME             +69.894s  
-event5   TOUCH_UP                +69.909s  0 (0)
 event5   TOUCH_FRAME             +69.909s  
-event5   TOUCH_DOWN              +96.373s  0 (0) 85.23/92.89 (255.75/171.00mm)
 event5   TOUCH_FRAME             +96.373s  
 event5   TOUCH_UP                +96.387s  0 (0)
 event5   TOUCH_FRAME             +96.387s  
-event5   TOUCH_DOWN              +115.360s 0 (0) 85.20/93.12 (255.67/171.42mm)
 event5   TOUCH_FRAME             +115.360s 
-event5   TOUCH_UP                +115.374s 0 (0)
 event5   TOUCH_FRAME             +115.374s 
-event5   TOUCH_DOWN              +129.771s 0 (0) 85.23/92.98 (255.75/171.17mm)
 event5   TOUCH_FRAME             +129.771s 
 event5   TOUCH_UP                +129.786s 0 (0)
 event5   TOUCH_FRAME             +129.786s 
-event5   TOUCH_DOWN              +138.171s 0 (0) 85.23/92.76 (255.75/170.75mm)
```

So every laptop restart is device added.

Quick solution was every laptop start call:

```
$ xinput disable "ELAN9009:00 04F3:2E36
$ xinput disable "ELAN9009:00 04F3:2E36 Stylus
```

```
$ xinput # when are devices disabled
...
∼ ELAN9009:00 04F3:2E36                     id=9    [floating slave]
∼ ELAN9009:00 04F3:2E36 Stylus              id=10   [floating slave]
...

$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=2e36 Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN9009:00 04F3:2E36"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN9009:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-0/i2c-ELAN9009:00/0018:04F3:2E36.0001/input/input19
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=3273800000000003
B: MSC=20
```

And now I try figure out what happened and how permanently remove this unreal device. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: clean the touchscreen